# Oracle 19.3 Change Query Notification Azure not working

Tags: c#, oracle, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

My change query notification service written in dotnet core is not working in Azure environment.
here is a part of code:

```
if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    OracleDependency.Port = 1005;

    DbCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand("select * from users");
    dbCommand.Connection = _connection;
    OracleCommand oracleCommand = ((OracleCommand)dbCommand);
    oracleCommand.AddRowid = true;
    var oracleDependency = new OracleDependency(oracleCommand);
    oracleDependency.QueryBasedNotification = true;
    oracleDependency.OnChange += eventHandler;
    oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The issue is the eventHandler does not get called. However the same code works fine in my local environment instead of Azure.
I have tried to check logs on the oracle azure server and found the following entry in the file -> /apps/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace/alert_orcl.log

```
kponepms: encountered ORA-12535 for location net8://(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<SOMEIP>)(PORT=1005))?PR=0 subname CHNF1261 after 7200000 milisecs
```

Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: that is clearly a timeout. you are not reaching the DB  from Azure. Is the database also in Azure IaaS ?

Comment: Yes the DB is in Azure Redhat, I am able to open the connection on port 1521. But for notifications I have used 1005.

Comment: you need a communication rule for the Azure IaaS server to open that port too. By default , in any IaaS server, all ports are usually closed

Comment: by the way, why are you using a different port for this ? keep in mind that the listener is not going to accept any connection in that port. I guess you don't have more than one port opened in the listener

Comment: Port 1005 and the IP in my error message are of Client's System. I believe oracle needs clients IP and Port for sending the notifications for CQN using OracleDependency class

Comment: I never used Change notification that way. Anyway, the error you are getting is coming from the network layer ( timeout ). Try to open the rule to allow inbound traffic in the IaaS host in the port 1005, but I am quite sure you will get a different TNS error.

Comment: I have opened the ports let me check again,

Comment: I checked again but it did not worked

Comment: which error do you get now ?

Comment: Its same I dont know from where it got the IP in the HOST value. because I don't find this IP anywhere.

Comment: Roberto I tried with opening all in bound, out bound ports and turned off the firewalls of both the azure machines, and then it worked. You are right somehow both the servers are not able to talk to each other on port 1005 and causing this issue.

Comment: so, is it fixed ? or do you get another error now ?

Comment: The issue still exists because of the data encryption setting in the sqlnet.ora like : 
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (AES256)

Comment: that is for another question. the original problem is solved, then. Can I post the answer ? I mean, if you are going to accept it

Comment: Sure please go ahead

Comment: answer provided ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As agreed, for the comments we shared, the issue was due to a problem in the communication between the Azure app and the database in IaaS.

By default, any IaaS Azure Server has all the ports closed, except the common ones ( 22, 443, 80..). Creating a new network rule for the IaaS inbound traffic should fix the issue.